# grep: annotate the occurrence number

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a text file with a format similar to:

```
PktType1 Header
PktType1 Pay
PktType1 Done
PktType0 Header
PktType0 Pay
PktType0 Done
...
```

What I'm trying to do is grep for all occurrences of `PktType0 Done` and then annotate which Nth occurrence it is along with the line number. For example:

```
1 42 PktType0 Done
2 65 PktType0 Done
3 75 PktType0 Done
```

Where 42, 65 and 75 are the line numbers and 1, 2 and 3 are simply a count of the occurrences. I suppose I could write it to a file and then show the line numbers. But I was wondering if there's a tool I can pipe this to that will do the same.

Comment: Always show expected output that you can get from the sample input you provide, not different output you could get from some other input. We need sample input/output we can copy/paste to test with to get a pass/fail result.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking to do beyond just pattern matching, and do additional formatting with line numbers and the match count, Awk is a better choice then grep

```
awk '/PktType0 Done/{ print ++count, NR, $0 }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if there's a tool I can pipe this to that will do the same.

Yes: [`nl`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=nl&apropos=0&sektion=1)

```
<log.txt grep -n 'PktType0 Done' | nl
```

Answer (score 1):

With example data taken from another answer:

```bsh
$ cat file
PktType0 Done
PktType1 Header
PktType1 Pay
PktType0 Done
PktType1 Done
PktType0 Header
PktType0 Pay
PktType0 Done
```

```bsh
$ awk '$0 == "PktType0 Done" { print ++count, NR, $0 }' file
1 1 PktType0 Done
2 4 PktType0 Done
3 8 PktType0 Done
```

The `awk` command ignores all lines except those precisely equal to the string `PktType0 Done`.  It prints the value of a counter, the current line number, and the line itself.

Change `$0 == "PktType0 Done"` to `/PktType0 Done/` to look for the string as a substring anywhere on any line.

Answer (score 0):

Not comparable with an `awk` solution, but here's an alternative. Given a slightly different sample:

```
PktType0 Done
PktType1 Header
PktType1 Pay
PktType0 Done
PktType1 Done
PktType0 Header
PktType0 Pay
PktType0 Done
```

The commands:

```bsh
$ paste <(awk '/Type0 Done/ { print ++c }' file) <(grep -n 'Type0 Done' file) | tr ':' ' ' | column -t
1  1  PktType0  Done
2  4  PktType0  Done
3  8  PktType0  Done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -n conf file |
  sed -Ee 's/^([[:digit:]]*):/\1 /' |
  cat -n
```

The `sed` step is because `grep -n` places a colon between the line number and the text, which was not indicated in your desired output.